# Is the plus (+) universal for adding an Item to a shopping cart?

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, globalization

Looking at globalization of our e-commerce. I was wondering if instead of having to translate "Add to Cart" in every language if simply a plus button will suffice.

[image: plus button]

I'm pretty new to globalization and I am wondering if the plus button is universal?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some e-commerce apps/webapps will use this to increment the *quantity* before adding to the cart...so it's not enough *on its own* to represent the notion of adding the item to a cart. However, the question doesn't provide any context within which this button will be used, so maybe it works in your particular scenario...

Comment: How about a shopping cart _icon_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the plus icon may be widely understood as "add", I would say it's a big risk to rely solely on it without any context. If localization is not feasible, my inclination would be to test an icon that shows a plus or arrow with a cart next to it, and also make this a very strong CTA using color/size/layout.

Answer (score 1):

For what it’s worth, the plus sign is probably more universally understood than the concept of shopping cart / basket / bag. It does not necessarily mean ‘Add *X* to *Y*’, however, but ‘Increase Amount of *X*’ – by 1 if not indicated otherwise – which may include automatic addition of another *X* to *Y*, especially if there is already at least 1 *X* in *Y*. Where amounts can be increased, they usually can also be decreased, so there would be a minus sign, too. That’s all true for English as well, of course.

[image: Symbols for various shopping cart actions]

Drag-drop is quite universal, by the way, but hardly supported by e-commerce sites as far as I know. It quite accurately resembles the physical action of putting some item into a container. This action can also be visualized with a down arrow and a generic container. Many online shopping sites just use a symbolic image of their metaphor for an container (without an arrow or plus sign) instead, i.e. most often a shopping cart, which can look quite different around the world. Note that in the physical world, most people will use a cart (or basket) for grocery shopping, but not for clothing for instance.